JsonConverter<T>.Write not being called

TL;DR I've set up a JsonConverter for a type in my ASP.NET Core application and while the Read method is correctly called when receiving data, the Write method isn't called when writing data.

I've created a JsonConverter for a custom type I've developed (an enum pattern implementation):
class MyEnum
{
    private MyEnum(int code, string description) 
    {
        Code = code;
        Description = description;
    }

    public int Code { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }

    public static MyEnum First = new(1, "First");
    public static MyEnum Second = new(2, "Second");

    public static Parse(string description) => description switch 
    {
        "First" => MyEnum.First,
        "Second" => MyEnum.Second,
    }

    public override string ToString() => Description;
}

The converter is straight-forward, resembling the code below:
public class MyEnumConverter : JsonConverter<MyEnum>
{
    public override T? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type _, JsonSerializerOptions _) => MyEnum.Parse(reader.GetString());

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions _)
        => writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
}

And configured ASP.NET Core to use this converter:
builder.Services
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(
            new MyEnumConverter());
    });

Surprisingly, when testing a Controller that returns that type, I get a Json with the whole class serialized, something like:
{ "code": 1, "description": "First" } 

However, when receiving a request, the Read method is correctly called!
This is the controller method signature, by the way:
public class Dto { public MyEnum Foo { get; set; } }

public async Task<Results<CreatedAtRoute<Dto>, BadRequest<string>>> Create(
    [FromBody] Dto dto);

Any idea why this could be happening?

Is AddJsonOptions the way to do this now? I thought it was done via builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(...)?

@DavidG it seems so... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-8.0#configure-systemtextjson-based-formatters-2

Since you're using the HttpResults setup, you have apply any configuration upon the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions type; here adding that converter.
builder.Services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Json.JsonOptions>(
    o => o.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new MyEnumConverter())
);


Note that this is not the same type as in builder.Services.AddJsonOptions(options => ...) which uses Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonOptions.
